# How to set control's location properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

My goal is to create report using Dev Express XtraReport. I'm using XRRichText and XRPictureBox controls.

My problem is that I can't set XRPictureBox control's location properly.

[image]

I want to Add XRPictureBox control after XRRichText control as it is shown in picture. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<Canvas>` - Lets you position child controls explicitly by specifying the distances
between their left, top, right, and bottom edges and those of the `<Canvas>`. I think it is exactly what you need. Here example how to use it:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Content=”TopLeft” Width=”85” Height=”30”
            Canvas.Top=”20” Canvas.Left=”20”/>
    <Button Content=”TopRight” Width=”85” Height=”30”
            Canvas.Top=”20” Canvas.Right=”20”/>
    <Button Content=”BottomLeft” Width=”85” Height=”30”
            Canvas.Bottom=”20” Canvas.Left=”20”/>
    <Button Content=”BottomRight” Width=”85” Height=”30”
            Canvas.Bottom=”20” Canvas.Right=”20”/>
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'm using wpf but I can't add wpf controls into XtraReport.

Comment: really strange lib from DevX.